# Does ReactiveUI for Xamarin supports ViewModel to ViewModel Navigation

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I am in process of learning Reactive UI for Xamarin and going through the documentation. However was not able to find that does it supports ViewModel to ViewModel Navigation. Is there any example application for same.

Comment: Are you using Forms?

Comment: Yes Thomas, I am using Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment navigation support for Xamarin forms is somewhat limited. So is is not possible to select if a Page should be Pushed Modal or not.
After trying to use RxUI nagivation I surrendered and now use RxUI together with xamvvm framework to deal with Page/ViewModel creation and ViewModel based navigation.

Check it out https://github.com/xamvvm/xamvvm/wiki

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this issue: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/1048 There are ways to do it but you'll have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it natively by following approach described here https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/05/15/data-first-approach-in-xamarin-forms/